# MapStruct exclude LOT of fields from mapper

Tags: spring-boot, entity, dto, mapstruct

Suppose I have a complex `entity` like the follow:

```
class A {

 private String a;
 private String b;
 private String c;
 /**
 * so on */
 private B bb;
 private C cc;
}
```

and the respective `DTO`:

```
class ADTO {

 private String a;
 private String b;
 private String c;
 /**
 * so on */
 private BDTO bb;
 private CDTO cc;
}
```

Now suppose C `entity` (and `CDTO`) has many variables and I want map is with just his ID field. For example

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
  public Interface AMapper {
  BDTO bToDto(B b);
  B bFromDto(BDTO bDto);

  CDTO cToDto(C c); // for this I want to map just the id!!
  C cFromDto(CDTO cDto); // even for this
}
```

How can I do?? I wouldn't write 50 times `@Mapper(properties = "someField", ignore = true)`, is there another method??

Thank you

Comment: for a single field, don't use  a mapper

Comment: you're right but the field is inside a nested bean.. I would like to do all in a single shot.. thanks anyway

Comment: @Mapper has `uses` field where we can define other classes to use. You can create a non-mapper impl for `C` class and add that impl in `uses` field.

Comment: Can you do a little example?? How can I create a non-mapper class...? Maybe I cam create a custom mapper that map just the Id as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate mapper for C class and add in `AMapper` class using `uses` field of `@Mapper`

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses={"CMapper.class"})
  public Interface AMapper {
  BDTO bToDto(B b);
  B bFromDto(BDTO bDto);

// remove below
//  CDTO cToDto(C c);
//  C cFromDto(CDTO cDto);
}

public CMapper{
   public C fromDTO(CDTO) {
      // add mapping for ID only
   }
   
   public CDTO toDTO(C) {
      // add mapping for ID only
   }

}
```